# Does anyone knows how to get OSM edit windows by URL

Tags: openstreetmap

I am trying to figure out how to get the edit map page for Open Street Map by Road id. I know that for the lat and long I can just use this URL: 
http://www.openstreetmap.org/edit#map=17/48.01588/37.80285

But I have no idea how to get is worked with road id. Because I don't know lat and long. I know only OSM road id.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy. Instead of the coordinates just pass the *way* parameter with the ID as the value. Example for the way with ID *24633810*:

> http://www.openstreetmap.org/edit?way=24633810

The same works for nodes and relations by passing the *node* or *relation* parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To go to the OpenStreetMap and open the user's default editor with a particular node or way, use http://www.openstreetmap.org/edit?node=ID or http://www.openstreetmap.org/edit?way=ID.

Provided the user is logged in it will open up the object in the user's editor. Depending on what they've set it could be a browser-based editor like iD (default), Potlatch 2, or it could go to JOSM with the remote control functionality of JOSM.

You can also call it with note=ID or gpx=ID to open on a particular note.

Answer (score 0):

You can get lat and lon using the OSM API. First get the XML for
the way record using
http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/$wayid

Then choose the id of one of the nodes (`<nd ref="...">`), e.g.
using an XML parser, and use this id for another OSM API call:
http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/$nodeid

Now you have an XML result with a node element where you can parse lon and lat
attributes.